# chaincode instantiation error: configured logging driver does not support reading

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am having issues with the deployment of go chaincode on Hyperledger Fabric. We successfully managed to install it but it does not get instantiated on the Peer. Instead, we receive the following error:

```
2019-12-02 13:32:42.309 UTC [chaincode.platform] func1 -> ERRO 47b Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "Error attaching: configured logging driver does not support reading
"
2019-12-02 13:32:42.310 UTC [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 47c Error building image: Post http://localhost:2375/build?t=dev-jdoe-dsb-5-c6e9dbb664408abd74a33e26282372104d35bf9cc52b5f46ebc43abcf214325d: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "Error attaching: configured logging driver does not support reading
"
2019-12-02 13:32:42.310 UTC [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 47d Build Output:
```

We do not even know where to start with the research to determine the root cause of this problem. Therefore, any suggestion as regards the directions to look for would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm getting similar error using AWS Mnaged Blockchain and trying to instantiate a chaincode

Comment: I had a similar issue when my harddrive was full